# How to get json data in kotlin using gson?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gson

This my json:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "strHomeTeam": "Liverpool",
            "strAwayTeam": "Swansea",
         }
     ]
}
```

This is my model:

```
data class Detail(@SerializedName("events") val events : EventDetail)
data class EventDetail(val strHomeTeam : String, val strAwayTeam: String)
```

This is my code to passing json data into model:

```
val body = response?.body()?.string()
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val eventData = gson.fromJson(body, Detail::class.java)
```

But I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 12 path $.events
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: In the JSON you have an array/list of EventDetail, while in your Detail class you have a simple field. Changing it to an Array<EventDetail> should solve your issue

Comment: thanks u, but how to acces EventDetail property, like "strHomeTeam"

Comment: from a Detail object you can access the array of EventDetails. Example: for (detail in eventData.events) { println(detail.srtHomeTeam) }

Comment: Thanks u so much, its solved. Have a good day :)

Comment: @Lukmanhakim mark currect answer if you solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
data class Detail( @SerializedName("events") val events : EventDetail)|
```

To

```
data class Detail( @SerializedName("events") val events : List<EventDetail>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Create your pojo class like below

```
  data class EventsModel(

    @field:SerializedName("events")
    val events: List<EventsItem?>? = null
)
```

where EventsItem class should be

```
  data class EventsItem(

    @field:SerializedName("strHomeTeam")
    val strHomeTeam: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("strAwayTeam")
    val strAwayTeam: String? = null
)
```

Comment: The `@SerializedName` is not needed, since variables already have a matching name. Also, the optional is not needed in case the values are mandatory in the JSON

Comment: I'm curious. Why add `field:` before `SerializedName`